@JoinColumn "occurs out of order" with spring-boot-3.3.2 (Hibernate 6.5.2 )
I am getting the error:
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Referenced column 'sub_categoryvid' mapped by target property 'id' occurs out of order in the list of '@JoinColumn's
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.internal.BinderHelper.findPropertiesByColumns(BinderHelper.java:544) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar:6.5.2.Final]

I have a table with compose id that has reference to itself:
Table diagram
represented like this:
public class SubCategoryItemPK implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "ItemID", insertable = false, updatable = false, unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer itemId;

    @Column(name = "SubCategoryVID", insertable = false, updatable = false, unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer subCategoryVId;

    ....
}

public class SubCategoryItem implements Serializable {


    @EmbeddedId private SubCategoryItemPK id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumnsOrFormulas(
            value = {
                    @JoinColumnOrFormula(
                            column =
                            @JoinColumn(
                                    referencedColumnName = "ItemID",
                                    name = "ParentItemID")),
                    @JoinColumnOrFormula(
                            formula =
                            @JoinFormula(
                                    referencedColumnName = "SubCategoryVID",
                                    value = "SubCategoryVID"))

            })
    private SubCategoryItem parentSubCategoryItem;
    
    ...

BinderHelper.java has this comment:
BinderHelper comment
When I debug I see that I got the error when is processing the second column (sub_categoryvid) and because is not the same than the first property (itemid):
BinderHelper code
Do you know how to fix this or a workaround??
This happend just when I start the application.
